# VBA code help, issue with ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue I'm hoping someone can help me fix. I'm attempting to search column W for all instances of the text "EB" "ER" and/or "LR". Then highlight that entire row. Below is the code but I'm getting issues with the Range as it keeps coming up with debug error on 'with sheets("sheet1").rng`the debug error is "Object doesn't support this property or method. Not sure what I've got wrong here but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
Sub HighlightCells()

Dim c As Range, FoundCells As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim lrow As Long, rng As Range, cell As Range

lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("W2:W" & lrow)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Sheet1").rng
Set c = .Cells.Find(What:="EB", After:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

Set c = .Cells.Find(What:="LR", After:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

Set c = .Cells.Find(What:="ER", After:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = c.Address
    Do
        If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
            Set FoundCells = c
        Else
            Set FoundCells = Union(c, FoundCells)
        End If

        Set c = .Cells.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And firstaddress <> c.Address
    FoundCells.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Else
    MsgBox "No DRC found."
End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(rng)?

Comment: You have `rng` dimmed as a `Range` and set. Use `With rng` and that ought to clear it up.

Comment: @AlexP `rng` is already a `Range`, so `With rng` is all they need. `rng` already knows about its parent `Sheet`, and `.Range(rng)` would probably result in `rng.Value` being passed to `.Range`, yielding error 1004 instead.

Comment: Another issue - you first try to find "EB" and `Set c =` that result, then immediately "reset" `c` to the result of finding "LR" - effectively getting rid of your previously found "EB", and so on. There's a better way to do this - filter the column for the values you want and then highlight the visible cells.

Comment: Thanks for the help I think that did it!  Also not sure why I didn't think to just filter the blanks out and then highlight everything left... made things much easier!